# Simple sql with GROUP BY HAVING AND WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one-to many tables. Table `ticket` and table `solution`. There are several solutions for each ticket. Solution have columns: `ticketId`, `status` and `serviceId`.

So, each ticket can resolved by one or several services. `Status` can be: `ready to resolve` and `done`. Only one service can done work for ticket. But also available case, where all solutions for ticket has status = ready to resolve.

I want get from tables pairs for all tickets: ticket row - solution row, where: serviceId = N and ticket has no other services with status = done.

I try solve my issue by this:

```
SELECT t.*, s.* FROM Ticket t 
JOIN Solution s ON t.id = s.ticketId 
WHERE s.serviceId = N 
GROUP BY s.ticketId HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.serviceId <> N AND s.status = 'done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

But this way do not work, because `WHERE s.serviceId = N` select only one row and ofcouse, sum always will be 0. If I remove WHERE, then sum start calculated correct, but I get from table `solution` always first row for ticket, but I want row with service = N.

How I can fix it?

Examples.

Ticket T. Solutions: S1 (service = N, status = ready), S2 (service = K, status = ready) -> get (T, S1).

Ticket T. Solutions: S1 (service = N, status = done), S2 (service = K, status = ready) -> get (T, S1).

Ticket T. Solutions: S1 (service = N, status = ready), S2 (service = K, status = done) -> null.

Ofcouse, can S3, S4 with services Q,W... But anyway: zero or one solution will have status = done.

Comment: I attempted an answer below but I feel that your data might not be normalized.

Comment: Please provide feedback to the thoughtful responses given below.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Where` clause and try this `Having` clause

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.serviceId = 'N' AND s.status = 'done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
   AND SUM(s.serviceId = 'N') > 0;
```

Considering `N` should be string

Comment: His query has other problems besides this.

Comment: @Prdp, all solutions for ticket can has status = 'ready to resolve'. Now update first post.

Comment: @YShinkarev - Can you add sample data and expected result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Whats that ? Are you talking about `N` ?

Comment: @Prdp, please see 'Examples'.

Comment: @Pdrp Just look at the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - That will work in `Mysql`. In `Mysql` you can have non aggregate columns in `select` when you are using `group by`

Comment: `That will work in Mysql` ... not in all versions, not even in the latest version, and it is logically undefined.

Comment: @YShinkarev - Still am not clear with your requirement. Can you add the sample data and result in table format

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery first to identify tickets which are not `done` for any service.  Then join this result to the `Ticket` table and again to `Solution`, including a condition which checks for solutions having a service ID of `N`.

```
SELECT t.*, s2.*
FROM Ticket t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ticketId
    FROM Solution
    GROUP BY ticketId
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 'done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) s1
    ON t.id = s1.ticketId
INNER JOIN Solution s2
    ON s1.ticketId = s2.ticketId AND
       s2.serviceId = 'N'
```